# React Router V4 - props not being passed to this.props.children from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

React.cloneElement is not passing props to child components when using react-router v4. I'm getting the history and location props. Just not getting any of the actions or props from mapStateToProps.

works fine when using react-router v3...only when i update version the props are not being passed.

```
class Main extends React.Component{
  render(){
    var clonedElements = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props);
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>
          <Link className='headLine'  to='/'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/DFkO2gb.png'/></Link>
          <p className='disclosure'>....</p>
        </h1>
          {clonedElements}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App>
         <Switch>
              <Route exact render={props => <CardsGrid {...props} /> }></Route>
              <Route exact path='/view/:postId' component={Single}></Route>
         </Switch>
            </App>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
) 


function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        posts: state.posts,
        comments: state.comments
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

const App = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));

export default App;
```

I'm expecting to see 2 props set by the initial state as props. I'm seeing none of those right now.

Comment: Which values do you expect to see a props and where. Also how is router const related to `Main`.

Comment: Are you getting history and location props?

Comment: Where is the `Main` component actually used ?

Comment: @SagarKhan yes I am getting history and location props.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm expecting to see an initial state I set in the App component using mapStateToProps function......I'm using connect function const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

Comment: @GaëlS, please see comment I made to Shubham for your answer.....if it's still not clear, please let me know because I'll try to be more precise. thank you

Comment: i've updated the question to shot the App component. thank you